# how to put the name of file as column name

Tags: r

Actually I have a lot of txt file in a folder and I make a list and then I put them all together. So far so good. Lets say I have files name like this "1a" "1b" "2a" "3b" etc I get a column from each file and make a data frame at the end.

What I cannot do now, is to make the files names as the column name of my final data frame. Lets say I get a column from "1a" I want to name it as 1a in my final data frame.

Is there anyway to do it?

Here is the names

```
> head(filelist)
[1] "./1a.txt" "./1b.txt" "./2a.txt" "./2b.txt" "./3a.txt" "./3b.txt"
```

Comment: You could use https://gist.github.com/psychemedia/150cb9901529da58124a to convert numbers in your file name to written numbers and then assign them as column names. Do remember to the owner if you use it. All the best!

Comment: You could use `names(data) <- basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(filelist))`.  Wrap with `make.names()` if you don't want the names to begin with a number.

Comment: @Richard Scriven that is a great solution. please mention it as an answer, I will like it , but I accepted the solution given below because I really learned few tips from his solution . Thanks Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to begin with numbers as your names here is what I would suggest:

```
# create example vector of file names for example
myFiles <- c("./1a.txt", "./1b.txt", "./2a.txt", 
             "./2b.txt", "./3a.txt", "./3b.txt")
```

---

```
# get a vector of filenames
myFiles <- list.files(<filePath>)
# paste the word file in front:
myFiles <- paste0("file.", gsub("\\./(.*)\\.txt$", "\\1", myFiles))

# add names to your data.frame columns:
names(df) <- myFiles
```

The regular expression "\./(.*)\.txt$" can be broken down as follows:

- \. tells the regex engine to match the literal dot "." In regex, "." by itself is the useful, yet dangerous "match any character."
- "/" and "txt" are  literals: match those characters.
- "$" is an anchor that forces the match to the end of the string.
- "()" is a capturing parentheses: it tells the engine to save that piece for later.
- ".*" within the parentheses says match anything in between the adjacent ("\./" and "\.txt$") subexpressions.
- the "\1" says to return the bit of text in the capturing parentheses.

For more on the wonderful world of regular expressions, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info). Also, this [site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which is linked in the SO link is where I learned much of what I use.

You will have to make sure that the orders of the names and the order of the columns match, but from your description, it sounds like you have this already.

If the list that contains the files is a named list, it should be event easier:

```
names(df) <- paste0("file.", names(fileList))
```

Comment: the problem now is that it put something like this ./1a.txt (it takes all as name)

Comment: yes both get rid of .txt and also .\ at the begining

Comment: no unfortunately it does not, it basically gives no name

Comment: I added more info above, if you need any more information, please let me know

Comment: can you please explain the patterns you used in your solution ? I know at first you scape the ./ then I don't get it and then you scape the .txt but what is $ ? then why do you use \\1 ? and why myFiles ?

Comment: @nik made some comments to help explain regex usage.

Comment: thanks I liked and I accepted it.